# Exporting a globe projection of a TIFF as a PDF

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to export a globe projection of the ['Natural Earth II with Shaded Relief, Water, and Drainages (large)'](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-natural-earth-2/10m-natural-earth-2-with-shaded-relief-water-and-drainages/) as a pdf but I keep getting the following error: `Could not transform bounding box to target CRS`

I'm using the following custom CRS:
`+proj=ortho +lat_0=29 +lon_0=98 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs`

I have also exported the ['Countries Map'](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/), the ['States, Provinces map'](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/) and the ['Graticules (10) map'](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-graticules/), all of which at least export using those CRS. The latter however does export some weird horizontal lines that should not be there.

I came across a few tutorials [such as this one](https://polemic.nz/2014/11/21/nz-azimuth-orthographic/) that seem to suggest that my problem has to do with improper clipping/projection of the layer. However, none of the solutions seem to work for me because the suggested Python scripts keep coming up with errors.

I'm working in QGIS 3.4.4.